# Getting collection's linklist to then get the handle to compare to main-menu in shopify

Tags: shopify

Say this is my navigational structure in shopify:

1. Shoes

   1. Flats
   2. Sandals
2. Bags

Currently I've gotten a fairly simple navigational component working, where if you're on a page (let's say shoes) the navigation on the page will highlight, because it matches the menu's handle with the page handle. Good so far:

```
{% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
     <span><a 

          {% if collection.handle == link.handle %}
               class="current"
          {% endif %}

     href="{{ link.url }}"> {{ link.title }}</a></span>
{% endfor %}
```

Now the question is, how do I check the sub-collection (Flats) and match it with it's parent collection to then do the same thing?

Comment: So when someone is on "Flats" page, you want both "Shoes" and "Flats" highlighted?

Comment: I just want shoes highlighted

Comment: Try this - `https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/`

Comment: How does this... help?

Comment: Isn't there a way to just do it through shopify...? This seems like a hack when I'm not too sure it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You need to adjust this condition

```
{% if collection.handle == link.handle %}
    class="current"
{% endif %}
```

so that it check for the internal links as well. Add this snippet before this condition

```
{% assign sub_link = false %}
{% assign inside_links_handle = link.handle %}
{% for inside_link in linklists[inside_links_handle].links %}
    {% if collection.handle == inside_link.handle %}
        {% assign sub_link = true %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And change the condition to this `{% if collection.handle == link.handle or sub_link == true %} class='current' {% endif %}`

Here you are looking inside the linklist which is inside another linklist (nested). More nesting levels, just iterate the code to consider inside levels. This should work.

Comment: Can you please check if `inside_links_handle` is `shoes`.